# USB host APIs public or blocked on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, usb, host

we know the Samsung Galaxy S3 will have USB host but do you guys have any knowledge if also the USB APIs will be public/accessible or blocked on the Samsung Galaxy S3 to allow developing apps requiring access to these APIs?

Comment: What API? Usb is handled at kernel driver level and there is usually nothing you can do from higher levels.

Answer (score 0):

It will be similar to other SGs.
Same access through the android OS/(Linux if rooted) as normally.

Comment: unfortunately not as easy. Just one example of what will be the biggest challenge for Android in the future: Platform Fragmentation. Different devices even from one company behave in detail totally different (e.g. NFC, USB). Even Samsung developer forum can't answer ("..Samsung is big company, we also don't know.." was their answer). Anyway, its extremely likely that the S3 will have the USB host APIs enabled (like the Galaxy Nexus has), but no guarantee. Need to wait until the phone is out and hook up an external keyboard via USB, if that works it means the APIs are enabled.

Comment: They might not have been told directly. But if they decided not to implement it, it would really surprise me.
But i'd post your comment as an answer to your own question, and then accept your own answer in 2 days time. might be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I have a galaxy S3 and apps like 'USB Host Viewer' and 'USB Host Controller' are able to see slave devices just fine with an OTG host adaptor connected.

I'm going to assume this means that the APIs are enabled but as I'm yet to find a usb driver that will l